# POST data and headers with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, web-services

Is it possible to send headers and POST data with `file_get_contents()`?

I'm trying with the following code

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'var1' => 'some content',
        'var2' => 'doh'
    )
);
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

but it's not working.

> "file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in(...)"

you know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Do you have allow-url-fopen enabled in php ini http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen?

Comment: @e_p yes, its enabled